# How to add design tab to palette in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

[image: this]

This is what my palette looks like, I want to know how to add other tabs like design and appCompact.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you are asking. The palette cannot be modified and is a container for components such as `button`, `texts`, etc.

Please refer to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/) for intro into Android Development.

`AppCompact` is a support library that allows for themes, colors, widgets, etc. to run on earlier devices i.e. backward compatibility.

The `design` view is accessed through the `res` folder in the `layout` folder. By default, called `activity_main.xml`.

You should go through the basics of android development so you can understand the structure, components and overview of android Studio.

**EDIT:**

See this [link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components) which shows you how to create `custom view components`

Please view this [link](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/layout-editor) which goes over the entire overview of the UI and how to use and customise the UI layout design(Very Useful!).

Comment: I want to add the support libraries components to the palette ( sadly it's not easy to clarify the question without pictures )

Comment: In Android Studio 3.1.2, the palette should contain all the needed components. Components that are not installed/downloaded should have a download icon next to it (arrow pointing down to a thick underline). See `EDIT` of post to see how to create custom views components.

Answer (score 0):

The folks that works on Android Studio redesigned the Palette window in Android Studio 3.1.2. Some of these widgets have been completely taken out.
"There is a new "Legacy" section and the "Advanced" section has gone. Along with it the NumberPicker, DataPicker, TimePicker, TextClock, Chronometer and, as far as I can see, the Transitions category has gone completely along with all its widgets."

"If you rely on any of the missing Widgets then my advice is don't upgrade until a workaround has been made available. There is no word from the Android Studio team as to why these widgets have been removed and no word on how to put them back."